# PythonTypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do 3 slices from a list of vectors from a txt file, with 2 columns, using conditions to separate the RGB.

But when I run the program the following error appears: "'float' object is not iterable". Can anyone help me?

```
#Conditions
B = 0
G = 0
R = 0

for i in range(0,len(vetor_x)):

    if vetor_x[i] <= 500:
        vetor_xB[B] = list(vetor_x[i])
        vetor_yB[B] = list(vetor_y[i])
        B += 1

    elif vetor_x[i] <= 600:
        vetor_xG[G] = list(vetor_x[i])
        vetor_yG[G] = list(vetor_y[i])
        G += 1

    elif vetor_x[i] <= 700:
        vetor_xR[R] = list(vetor_x[i])
        vetor_yR[R] = list(vetor_y[i])
        R += 1

print('####### vetor_xB #######')
print(vetor_xB)
print('####### vetor_yB #######')
print(vetor_xB)
print('####### vetor_xG #######')
print(vetor_xG)
print('####### vetor_yG #######')
print(vetor_yG)
print('####### vetor_xR #######')
print(vetor_xR)
print('####### vetor_yR #######')
print(vetor_yR)
```

When I try to run it, this causes this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste4.py", line 30, in <module>
    vetor_xB[B] = list(vetor_x[i])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Please help me!

Comment: what is your `vector_xB`? Looks like it's a floating point.

Comment: @KevinFang Is a list of values from the first column within the range> = 500

Comment: `vetor_x.append(float(X))` why into float?

Comment: @user5173426 Because they are not integers

Comment: @Fulana I mean, what's it before this block of code, how do you define and initialize it.

Comment: Could you also show what is the expected result for each line? I believe what you're trying to do can be done in a much more concise code.

Comment: @KevinFang There is nothing before, just this file opening and the attempt to slice the lists.

Comment: @ParvBanks The expected result is vector_xB = [400.00000, 401.10373, 409.54288, 425.24905, 442.71341, 470.96112, 488.7771, 499.79489, 499.91208, 500.00000]; vector_yB = [46.5713, 42.8136, 103.12, 12.6044, 262.43, 680.958, 171.28, 39.846, 41.1616, 39.2299]; vector_xG = [500.00000, 523.70581, 540.81854, 579.26355, 593.3288, 600.0000]; vector_yG = [39.2299, 38523.1, 31554.2, 243.866, 90.6795, 212.789] ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot split an `int` or `float` type into a `list`.
You can convert them to `str` using `str(vetor_x[i])` first if this is what you're going for.
`list()` will attempt to split a string into each character.
For example, `list('abc')` will give you `['a','b','c']`.
For `int` and `float`, this cannot be done because they are not iterables.

It does not look like you intend to split your `vetor_x[i]` into each character. It looks like you just want to store the values into `vetor_xB[B]`, in which case, you should be creating an empty list with that many `None` or `0` variables and then your code to replace them with your

```
for i in range(0,len(vetor_x)):

    if vetor_x[i] <= 500:
        vetor_xB[B] = vetor_x[i]
        vetor_yB[B] = vetor_y[i]
        B += 1
.......
```

will work.
So you should actually create `vetor_xB = [None]*500` to get `vetor_xB = [None, None, x500...]` before the above code will work

Comment: Hi @ycx, I want to split that array up there in pairs, by the x-coordinate (first column). Ex: 400 <= B> = 500, 500 <= B> = 600 and 600 <= B> = 700 and store them in new arrays. I do not know if I did not understand what you explained, but it still made a mistake.

Comment: @Fulana If that is the case, you can do a `vetor_x.sort()` (optional if you want to sort or just store them as of the original order), Then do a direct `for i in vetor_x:` loop, check for the `<=` and `append` the floats to `vetor_xB` directly.